# CSS/HTML: Code for double down/up pointing angle

Tags: html, css, unicode

We have double left pointing angle code (Name: `&laquo;`    Number `&#171;` looks like «) and double right pointing angle code (Name: `&raquo;` Number: `&#187;` looks like »).

Is there double up/down pointing angle code in HTML? Or should we resort to CSS rotate on right/left to get up/down double pointing angles?

Comment: Probably the closest is U+219f. It is a two-headed arrow with a stem.

Answer (score 9):

`&#65085;` should work for up-pointing and `&#65086;` for down-pointing. For more, view this link [http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=up-pointing+double+angle](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=up-pointing%20double%20angle)

Answer (score 4):

You can create it by rotating the right pointing double arrow

```
<div class="up_arrow">&raquo;</div>

.up_arrow{
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

Fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/zyonpe2n/

This will give the most consistent looking arrow. If you are using `&raquo;` on your page already.